# Boot directly into a virtual machine (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, vmware

I want Mac OSX 10.11 on my laptop. But thats not possible through hackintoshing for some reasons.

I have setup a virtual machine in VMWare. The virtual machine with El Capitan works perfectly alright.

The question is that is there anyway i can directly boot into the El Capitan virtual machine ? Like when i power on my laptop, i get an option to boot directly into VM or boot into Windows 7.

So is there any way i can go about ?

Hope anyone replies.

Thanks Alot

Default OS :- Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Quick answer : no. 
Longer answer : Because VM is run on top of main OS.

Answer (score 0):

No.  And if you could it would still be against Apple TOS.